# Drag&Drop in vaadin with clientSideCriteria

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have several types of components which are dragable. I have to ensure that the currently dragged component can only be dropped on a drop-target with the same type.

The ClientSideCriterion **ContainsDataFlavor** seems apropriate for this task. But i found no way to mark my draggable components of which type they are.

With this i can formulate that only components of type x are allowed drop-targets:

```
@Override
public AcceptCriterion getAcceptCriterion()
{
    return new ContainsDataFlavor("ComponentType_ONE");
}
```

But how can i mark a `DragAndDropWrapper` with the tested type?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the criterion **ContainsDataFlavor** is unfortunately not appropriate for my use-case.

After a lot of research and debugging i decided to implement my own ClientSideCriterion. This is not really hard, you only need two classes with basically only one method, thats it.